# Write the solution- so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in

Tags: php

Hi i have tried the above on codewars(php) https://www.codewars.com/kata/multiples-of-3-or-5/train/php/5e0809cadf8a12001386b527 and the below answer works

```
<?php
function solution($number){
     $multiples = [];
 for ($i=1;$i<$number;$i++){


       if($i%3==0 || $i%5==0)
          {
              array_push($multiples,$i);
          }

     }

  return array_sum($multiples);
} ?>
```

But there's a condition that they have mentioned and  I am not sure how it meets that

Condition ' Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once.'?

So when we use '||' aren't we just saying

> if condition one or if condition two is true, return true , and isn't it true when both condition one and two are true?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use array_unique for your array